# Php, turn random dates into a consistent format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a page where a user can upload a .csv of urls and dates. The format looks like this:

```
http://www.google, 1/05/2013
http://www.yahoo, 1/04/2013
```

I then open the file, read the file and put it into a database for other uses.

I need my script to handle different date formats some how. It could be a regex or splitting the string etc.

So far the formats I've been handed are

```
month/day/year
day/month/year
year-day-month
```

I need to be able to turn any date someone gives me consistently into the same date format to insert into the database.

Currently I have this function to check if the date is in US format (month/day/year).

```
protected function checkDate($handle) {
    $europeanDateFormat = false;

    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== false) {
        $dateChunks = explode("/", $row[1]);

        if (isset($dateChunks[0]) && $dateChunks[0] > 12) {
            $europeanDateFormat = true;
            break;
        } else if (isset($dateChunks[1]) && $dateChunks[1] > 12) {
            $europeanDateFormat = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    rewind($handle);

    return $europeanDateFormat;
}
```

And then I flip them around if its not in the US format, as you can see I wasnt able to deal with the dashes when it was uploaded.

```
protected function makeDateAmerican($date) {
    $dateChunks = explode('/', $date);
    $rawDate = $dateChunks[1] . '/' . $dateChunks[0] . '/' . $dateChunks[2];
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rawDate));
}
```

Additionally this script needs to handle the long and sort formats:

```
month = 1 or 01
day = 1 or 01
year = 13 or 2013
```

In the end I need to get all dates into the same format for the stringtotime function:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateString));
```

Comment: Either strictly enforce a single date standard, or add another field to the form for users to specify the formatting of their dates. Otherwise have fun guessing what date 11/12/10 is supposed to be.

Comment: You can't. 01/02/2013 - ist that february or january? strtotime() might sometimes guess corrctly, sometimes not

Comment: `strtotime("13/12/2012")` turned out to be a disappointment.

Comment: You need to sanitize the input at the source, or limit formatting to a few unambiguous formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime` which seems to use pseudo-intelligence and parses [a variety of date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("5/6/2012")); // May 6, 2012 (slash)
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("5-6-2012")); // Jun 5, 2012 (dot/tab/dash)
```

IMHO, it is probably as close as you can get.